# Stay on same page after refresh because of submit button click

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've created three button in same file with php extension. When I click one button others information get hidden. I'm doing it using **javascript** function call.

Now, When I do some query and submit it to excute from server side the page get refresh and I'm seeing the content under the button which I make visible for first entering into the page.
I change the default visible button content than I can't see result of other two button after they are submitted.

Now, I want to see the content of each button after it's submission. How can I'll do that?

Comment: research events preventDefault method

Comment: Please share what did you try.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

you can manage visibility of input in php like this

```
if(isset($_request['btn1'])){
echo("<input type='text' value='result of btn1' style='display=block' />");
echo("<input type='text' value='result of btn2' style='display=none' />");

}

if(isset($_request['btn2'])){
echo("<input type='text' value='result of btn1' style='display=none' />");
echo("<input type='text' value='result of btn2' style='display=block' />");
}
```

please share your code